# HOw to Include many level objects in LINQ Queries

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

im using Silverlight and Ria services i have the following linq function in ria that returns an object called DependantPerson:

```
    public IQueryable<DependantPerson> GetDependantPersons(int PerID)
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.DependantPerson
            .Include("Person1")
            .Where(dp => dp.Person_FK == PerID)
            .OrderBy(dp => dp.ID);
    }
```

now DependantPerson is related to another Object called Person1 wich i included in this query, and Person1 is in turn related to a third Object called SimpleListValue, How can i tell LINQ that i also what to inclue SimpleListValue in Person1 so i can later use it in binding at XAML side as following:

...**sdk:Label Content="{Binding Person1.MotherName}"**

...**sdk:Label Content="{Binding Person1.SimpleListValue.Label}"**

the first example Person1.MotherName works just fine but the second Person1.SimpleListValue.Label is not working and i think the problem is my LINQ query

any help is appreciated thank you for your time and bear with me

Answer (score 0):

Use DataLoadOptions.LoadWith()

See examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386917(v=VS.90).aspx

You must specify DataLoadOptions and assign in to the DataContext instance before executing any queries.

this is an answer [jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114994/jay) gave me on [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303930/mvc2-net-pass-object-from-viewmodel-to-view-and-acces-it). I hope this helps

Comment: How can i use it if i have DomainDataSource on xaml side ?